# How to use Linkedin-iphone current_user in an other view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, linkedin-api

I'm using this LinkinClientLibrary https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

I'm little confused, it's a single view app the DEMO, it working, I've managed to make it work in my own app.. But now after the successful login of the user, I want to show a tableview with all his/her connections and maybe a detail screen of a connection...

So I have now a login screen and after successful authenticate the user I perform a segue to a tableview and how can I use the current users connections in that tableview or even if its simpler to explain the current users data in a view (and check that the user is still connected)

Thnx Fred

Answer (score 0):

There's another iPhone sample client here:
    https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

In that there is a profile view that uses the authentication information from LinkedIn to make calls to LinkedIn - it demonstrates both read and write functionality.  Check out the code to see if it answers your questions.